# php mysqli bind_param $insert->execute() always returns true

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a model method that always returns true when I execute. Even if I give it a random id number that does not exits in my database

My model method

```
public function updateSetting($data, $id)
{
    $con = new Database();
    $insert = $con->mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `settings` SET `value` = ? WHERE `id` = ?');
    $insert->bind_param('ss', $data, $id);
    if ($insert->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My controller method

```
public function updatePasswordSetting()
{
    if (isset($_POST['pw_setting'])) {
        $strong_pw = 1;
    } else {
        $strong_pw = null;
    }
    if (!$this->settings_model->updateSetting($strong_pw, 'asdf')) {
        exit('Could not update password setting');
    }
}
```

In the method above I give the updateSetting controller method a nonsense parameter like 'asdf' and the method still returns true even though no such id exists in my settings table.

What is happening?

Comment: You might want to check the [affected rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php)

Comment: It's returning true as the statement has executed correctly, as the above  comment says, its a case of checking if it has actually updated anything which should solve your problem.

Comment: Wow. The statement can execute correctly even if the parameters are wrong and the table columns don't exists? Ok thanks guys. Will just check to see which rows are affected.

Comment: If you provide non existing column names, then you will get an error.

Comment: but shouldnt the execute return false because my table has no column 'asdf'. When I enter the command UPDATE `settings` SET `value` = 1 WHERE `id` = `asdf` directly into the sql console in phpmyadmin I get the error Unknown column 'asdf' in 'where clause'. Shouldnt this return false?

Comment: do you realize the difference between a column name and a data literal?

Comment: Yep. Your username and comment just made me realize. Sorry its very late.

Comment: So it's time to use my username and *answer* as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior. If `execute()` returns `true`, this just means that there was no SQL code / database / network error when executing the statement. It is natural to *not* consider it an *error* if no records are affected by a statement.

As @SearchAndResQ has suggested, you could check the affected rows. But be aware that this has its caveats, so you should read MySQL's [ROW_COUNT() documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) and [mysql_affected_rows() documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html) first (one of them must be used by PHP behind the scenes).

Notably, the behavior with `UPDATE` depends on flags which are set when the connection to the database is established, and it might behave unexpectedly with `REPLACE` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Personally, I prefer another method in such situations. I first `SELECT` the record(s) in question `FOR UPDATE` and then look into the result set to check if any records are affected. Then I am doing the update while the records are still locked. You need to use transactions for that (which I am doing anyway, so the additional effort is not too bad).

IMHO, that method is more portable, and its results are more understandable, so it is generally safer than the `affected_rows` mechanism. Its disadvantage is that you need to use transactions and that it might be slower.

Comment: This answer, although the bluntly correct by itself, won't  provide any help for the OP

Comment: @YourCommonSense Why? The OP's question exactly was why `execute()` does return `true` even in cases where actually no update happens due to the `WHERE` condition, and I think I have exactly answered that question in the first paragraph of my answer. The OP did not ask for a solution, he just had an understanding problem, so the other paragraphs are additional information which the OP may or may not use.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, your very basic premises are wrong. In fact,

## You shouldn't care whether execute() returned false or not

It could happen only in case of some severe database error. But in such a case it is no point in going into much details about particular operation where error happened to happen. In case of a severe database error just show a generic Server error page.

On the other hand, as a programmer, you *must* get to know, **what particular error** happened during the update, in order to be able to fix it. And your code does nothing to help you.

I wrote an article, [PHP error reporting basics](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) explaining this stuff. To make your code right, just get rid of all the result checking conditions in both functions

```
public function updateSetting($con, $data, $id)
{
    $insert = $con->mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `settings` SET `value` = ? WHERE `id` = ?');
    $insert->bind_param('ss', $data, $id);
    $insert->execute();
}

public function updatePasswordSetting()
{
    if (isset($_POST['pw_setting'])) {
        $strong_pw = 1;
    } else {
        $strong_pw = null;
    }
    $this->settings_model->updateSetting($strong_pw, 'asdf');
}
```

and then write an error handler or a global try catch to show a generic server error page.

As you may notice, you should also never create a new database connection in every function. Instead you should create only one and then pass it in other functions as a parameter.

Lastly, the logic behind your code is also wrong. Attempting to update a non-existent row is not an error whatsoever. Not to mention that such a situation should never occur, as your code ought to validate the user id and disallow any id other than current user's. If you are assuming that value could be deliberately anything then any user will be able to change any other user's password.